# How to know shell scitpt is executed successfully when using php exec method

Tags: php, shell, exec

I am running shell script using exec in php, exec is successfully executes and give 0 as result code. is there any way to check all shell script is executed successfully or not?

Comment: `exec()` only returns the successcode if the script has finished without errors. So yes, in that case everything is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If the exit code is zero, then the script ran successfully to it's end.

The exit code code howover does not imply that your shell script worked internally, but rather it did not fail to execute. It is your shells script's duty to return a valid exit code whenever you want to state that something went wrong.

Furthermore it is good practice to explicitly quit with `exit 0` to state that your script is ran with no error. What an exit code <> 0 means it totally up to you.

Example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "This script will always fail"

# return exitcode <> 0 to state that something went wrong
exit 1
```